# Node.js controlling GPIO pins

Tags: gpio, node.js

Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian, gpio node.js utility following these instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pi-gpio

Everything installed fine with no errors until I attempted to use the code. Whenever I try to open a pin or for that matter do anything with any GPIO pin it returns this error:

"Error when trying to open pin 40

gpio-admin: failed to change group ownership of /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio21/direction: No such file or directory"

I checked and there is no gpio directory under the virtual folder. I don't really know why this isn't working I even tried running everything as the root user to no avail. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    gpio.open(msg, "output", function(err) {
      gpio.write(msg, 1, function() {
        gpio.close(msg);
      });
    });
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: There are several different models of Pi.  There are several different operating systems.

Comment: Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian

Comment: Show us the code you use that causes the error.  It is possible that the pin is already open from a prior run too.

Comment: @MatthewPitzer - please put the code in your question where you can format it properly, not in comments.

Comment: Just added it to the main post

Comment: It is probably because the pin is already open.  This GPIO code is actually quite a pain to use because things can get stuck.  I had to modify my own copy of the GPIO library to add an `.openGrab()` method that would force the pin closed first before opening it so that it wouldn't get stuck open from a prior abnormal exit of the program which happens all the time in debugging.

Comment: *"I checked and there is no gpio directory under the virtual folder."* -> That's because it's actually somewhere else, see the answer to the duplicate.  Unfortunately you can't create symlinks in `/sys`.  Someone needs to update `pi-gpio`, or else you need to find a way to set the directory properly.

Comment: ...if you do find a way to do that, leave a comment and I'll reopen this so you can add it as an answer.  Otherwise you might want to write a new question, "How to change gpio directory for node.js pi-gpio?".